# Expected initializer before * token

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors

So I have this header file:

```
#pragma once

#include "engine.hpp"

namespace spacecubes
{
  extern engine* _engine;
}
```

and the included engine.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

#include "glinclude.hpp"
#include "debug.hpp"
#include "convert.hpp"
#include "renderer.hpp"
#include "global.hpp"

namespace spacecubes {
    void display();

    class engine {
        renderer renderengine;

    public:
        void start(int argc, char* argv[]);
        void stop(int status = 0);
        void poll();

        renderer getRenderEngine() {return renderengine;}
    };
}
```

What the compiler reported later on was:

```
g++  -c -o bin/obj/engine.o src/engine.cpp
In file included from src/engine.hpp:9,
                 from src/engine.cpp:1:
src/global.hpp:7: error: expected initializer before '*' token
src/engine.cpp: In function 'void spacecubes::display()':
src/engine.cpp:5: error: '_engine' was not declared in this scope
```

I don't get it. What did it mean that it expected an init? Thanks in advance!

Comment: look at `src/global.hpp:7:`, the error is there

Comment: @fawques I know, I just couldn't understand the error.

Comment: Think about what you're doing: including `engine.hpp` in `global.hpp` and `global.hpp` in `engine.hpp`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is isn't the #pragma once going to help?

Comment: @YoshiHi It will guard against multiple inclusion but it won't make the compiler recursively resolve references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
#include "engine.hpp"
```

with a forward declaration:

```
namespace spacecubes { class engine; }
```

Comment: Thanks, it got past that error but now the linker starts complaining about having undefined symbols. I think I may have to figure that myself now. Thanks again.

Comment: @YoshiHi define the symbol - in a single implementation file (cpp file), you need to have `namespace spacecubes { engine* _engine; }` - this is a definition of the declared symbol.

Comment: Ahh, thanks Luchian! I forgot to make up for the promise I made to the compiler: Adding `engine* spacecubes::_engine` to main.cpp. *Bangs head on wall*